# Multiple inputs update multiple textarea's

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea

exactly what the title describes.

i'm wanting 1 set of 6/7 input fields to be able to update 4/5 different textareas for different templates to copy paste from with the input elements.

ive tried using getelementsbyclassname but it doesnt seem to work with multiple textareas.

a simple example for multiple inputs updating multiple textarea's would be enough to play with.

This is what i have so far, and its not complete.

```
1 name: <input type="text" name="1stTarget" onblur="tst1(this);" /><br />
2 name: <input type="text" name="2ndTarget" onblur="tst1(this);" /><br />
Email address: <input type="text" name="3rdTarget" onblur="tst1(this);" /><br />
Phone #: <input type="text" name="4thTarget" onblur="tst1(this);" /><br />
Schedule: <input type="text" name="5thTarget" onblur="tst1(this);" /><br />
<textarea name="result" id="result1" onClick="this.select();" class="disable">Hello 1stTarget, 2ndTarget i would like to confirm your email address 3rdTarget and phone # 4thTarget and the time you will be at work 5thTarget</textarea>
<br />
<textarea name="result2" id="result2" onClick="this.select();" class="disable">1stTarget and 2ndTarget updated their 5thTarget and their 4thTarget including their 3rdTarget</textarea><input type="reset" value="Reset!" />
```

using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tst1(elm){
    var trgt=document.getElementById('result1');
    trgt.value=trgt.value.replace(elm.getAttribute('name'), elm.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please show some code and can you explain exactly what you are trying to do? You want an input to update textareas, but update the textareas into what?

Comment: sorry, new to this site. didn't realize i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would not try to replace the text in the textarea but instead simply build the string you need from your inputs and set the text when that's done. Something like the below would work for that:

**Note** THe main function you need is jQuery's [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$('#fill').click(function(elm) {
    var hasErrors=false;
    var $updateElms=$('.update');
    $updateElms.removeClass('hasError');
    $updateElms.each( function(i,e){
        if($(e).val()==''){
          hasErrors=true;
          $(e).addClass('hasError');
        }
    });
    if(hasErrors) return;
    var name1 = $updateElms.eq(0).val();
    var name2 = $updateElms.eq(1).val();
    var email = $updateElms.eq(2).val();
    var phone = $updateElms.eq(3).val();
    var schedule = $updateElms.eq(4).val();
     
    var text0 = 'Hello '+name1+', '+name2+' I would like to confirm your email address '+email+' and phone # '+phone+' and the time you will be at work '+schedule;
    var text1 = 'Hi '+name1+', '+name2+' we have recieved your confirmation that your email address is '+email+' and phone # is '+phone+' and that you will be at work '+schedule;
    var text2 = 'Hello '+name1+', '+name2+' we have attempted to reach you via your email address '+email+' and phone # '+phone+' to advise that you missed your shift at '+schedule;
  
    $('.result:eq(0)').val(text0);
    $('.result:eq(1)').val(text1);
    $('.result:eq(2)').val(text2);
  });
```

```css
.hasError{
    color:red;
    background-color:#F9B9B9;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

1 name:
<input type="text" class="update"/>
<br />
2 name:
<input type="text" class="update"/>
<br />
Email address:
<input type="text" class="update"/>
<br />
Phone #:
<input type="text" class="update"/>
<br />
Schedule:
<input type="text" class="update"/>
<br />
<input type="button" id="fill" value="Fill Textareas"/>
<br />
<textarea name="result" class="disable result"></textarea>   
<br />
<br />
<textarea name="result" class="disable result"></textarea> 
<br />
<br />
<textarea name="result" class="disable result"></textarea>                                                 
<br />
<input type="reset" value="Reset!" />using
```

Comment: i agree, but i want different textarea's with the provided inputs for different messages generated by each input.

Comment: @KyleH8CH Do you have one set of inputs that load a bunch of different messages in various text areas, or do you have several sets of inputs where each set is paired with a textarea that the inputs manipulate?

Comment: one set of inputs loading a bunch of different messages in various text areas. i updated my original post with multiple textarea's and an example difference

Comment: can i say i love you @DelightedD0D? That is exactly what I was looking for. I searched everywhere.

Comment: @KyleH8CH Happy to help, the main function here is jQuery's [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) which lets you target the element at a specific index from a group of elements matching your selector (it lets you choose which text area etc you want to work with)